# Custom spacing of bars in ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph a dataset in ggplot2. I want to make a graph that will have bars touching if they are the same cell colour, and then a gap between each colour. e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  cell_color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red"),
  cell_type = c("neuron", "sc", "neuron", "sc"),
  value = c(10, 15, 8, 12)
)

# Define the custom order of bars
custom_order <- c("blue_neuron", "blue_sc", "red_neuron", "red_sc")

# Create the bar graph with custom dodge width
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(paste(cell_color, cell_type, sep = "_"), levels = custom_order), y = value, fill = cell_color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red")) +
  labs(x = "Cell Type", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Creates
[image: graph]

How can I make the two blue columns touch, and then a gap, then have the two red columns touch. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using facets:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(paste(cell_color, cell_type, sep = "_"), levels = custom_order), y = value, fill = cell_color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width = 1, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red")) +
  labs(x = "Cell Type", y = "Value") +
  facet_wrap(~cell_color, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or you could map the bars where you want and use custom axis labels:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = c(1:2, 4:5), y = value, fill = cell_color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width = 1, color = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:2, 4:5), minor_breaks = NULL,
                     labels = custom_order) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red")) +
  labs(x = "Cell Type", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]